# namedspace models has_many through throwing errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

These are the models that  I am having problem with.

```
class Admin::FilterGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :admin_filter_groups_agents,class_name: "Admin::FilterGroupsAgents"
    has_many :agents, through: :admin_filter_groups_agents
end

class Admin::FilterGroupsAgents < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :admin_filter_group, :class_name => "Admin::FilterGroup",foreign_key: "admin_filter_group_id"
  belongs_to :agent, :class_name => "Agent",foreign_key: "agent_id"
end

class Agent < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :admin_filter_groups_agents,class_name: "Admin::FilterGroupsAgents"
    has_many :admin_filter_groups, through: :admin_filter_groups_agents
end
```

When I try calling `Admin::FilterGroup.first.agents` I am getting the following error:

```
    irb(main):001:0> Admin::FilterGroup.first.agents
  Admin::FilterGroup Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `admin_filter_groups`.* FROM `admin_filter_groups`   ORDER BY `admin_filter_groups`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  Agent Load (63.2ms)  SELECT `agents`.* FROM `agents` INNER JOIN `admin_filter_groups_agents` ON `agents`.`id` = `admin_filter_groups_agents`.`agent_id` WHERE `admin_filter_groups_agents`.`filter_group_id` = 1
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'admin_filter_groups_agents.filter_group_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `agents`.* FROM `agents` INNER JOIN `admin_filter_groups_agents` ON `agents`.`id` = `admin_filter_groups_agents`.`agent_id` WHERE `admin_filter_groups_agents`.`filter_group_id` = 1
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'admin_filter_groups_agents.filter_group_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `agents`.* FROM `agents` INNER JOIN `admin_filter_groups_agents` ON `agents`.`id` = `admin_filter_groups_agents`.`agent_id` WHERE `admin_filter_groups_agents`.`filter_group_id` = 1
```

How to solve this?

---

```
class CreateAdminFilterGroups < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :admin_filter_groups do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end


class CreateAdminFilterGroupsAgents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :admin_filter_groups_agents do |t|
      t.references :admin_filter_group, index: true
      t.references :agent, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end


class CreateAgents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :agents do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :user, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: As the SQL query error shows, the foreign key needs to be admin_filter_group_id instead of filter_group_id. The model code seems fine. Can you post the code for the 3 models' migrations?

Comment: the code seems right only... but somehow it is taking it wrong.. I am confused... bug in rails?

Comment: So the join table in the DB, is it getting created with the correct column names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try specifying the foreign_key on the other side of the association as well, in both the `Agent` and `Admin::FilterGroup` classes.

So for `Agent`:

`has_many :admin_filter_groups_agents, class_name: "Admin::FilterGroupsAgents", foreign_key: "agent_id"`

And for `Admin::FilterGroup`:

`has_many :admin_filter_groups_agents,class_name: "Admin::FilterGroupsAgents", foreign_key: "admin_filter_group_id"`